# How can Reuse executeQuery in the session one

Tags: java, sql-server

I doing BDD with cucumber:

Step 1: run excecuteQuery -> show value column 3 in DB correct (example:1.000)

Step 2: run API plus amount into DB (example: 2.000)

Step 3: Re-excecuteQuery => value show incorrect (expected :3.000)

```
public int variableTotalAmount() { 
    MysqlConnect mysqlConnect = new MysqlConnect(); 
    int amountVariable = 0; 
    String sql = "sql"; 
    try { 
        Statement stmt = mysqlConnect.connect().createStatement(); 
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql); 
        while (rs.next()) { 
            amountVariable = rs.getInt(3); 
        } 
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    finally {
        mysqlConnect.disconnect(); 
    } 
    return amountVariable; 
}
```

Comment: public int variableTotalAmount() {
        MysqlConnect mysqlConnect = new MysqlConnect();
        int amountVariable = 0;
        String sql = "c";
        try {
            Statement stmt = mysqlConnect.connect().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                amountVariable = rs.getInt(3);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            mysqlConnect.disconnect();
        }
        return amountVariable;
    }

Comment: From this, "c" is the name of a stored proc is it? What happens if you run it from SSMS?